# How to limit the number of files/ total sizes can be downloaded by user per hour in Sharepoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, file-download

In Sharepoint Online, I want to avoid that users could download or copy the full content of a library or a site he has access to. The goal is to avoid that before leaving the company an employee download all documents he has access to before working for a competitor.

Finally, let say I want to limit the number of files and total sizes that users can download per hour or per login time?

Do we have any solution to reach those goals? or any suggestions/keywords I did try to research but no luck. Much appreciated your help.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps for stop downloading the content.

```
1- On the site, click Settings > Site Settings.

2- Under Search, click Search and offline availability.

3- In the Offline Client Availability section, select 'No'.
```

[Prevent users from downloading content from site](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/prevent-users-from-downloading-content-from-a-site-98821ec7-cc99-4393-a002-f73370ba6694)

Comment: It doesn't resolve my problems